# Error mounting drive in google colab unsuccessfully

Tags: google-colaboratory

recently i could not mount my drive in Colab
after running this code i am still have mount error....is there any beautiful solution to this

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

after several attempt in trying to mount my google drive i changed the GPU from T4 to CPU it also failed many times before mounting successfully but the information that accompanied the mounting error was too many files in root folder. after that i created a sub-folder in the root folder and remount still yet i was still having mounting error